# For a given function, answer yes or no whether limit exists

Tags: limits, functions

Given a function $f$:
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
2+x & \mbox{if } \; x<0 \\
x^3 & \mbox{if } \; 0 \le x<1 \\
\sin\tfrac{\pi x}{2} & \mbox{if } \; x \ge 1
\end{cases}$$

Do the following limits exist or not?

- $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$
- $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$

Comment: What is the function?

Comment: first time using it, I uploaded the function

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Since you're new, I formatted your question for you. Perhaps you can edit and add your thoughts?

Comment: thank you :) @StackTD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{0^-}f (x)=\lim_{0^-}(2+x)=2$$

$$\lim_{0^+}f (x)=\lim_{0^+}x^3=0$$

$$\implies \lim_{0^-}f (x)\ne \lim_{0^+}f (x) $$

> and

$$\lim_{1^-}f (x)=\lim_{1^-}x^3=1$$
$$\lim_{1^+}f (x)=\lim_{1^+}\sin (\frac {\pi x}{2})=1$$
$$\implies \lim_{1^-}f (x)=\lim_{1^+}f (x) $$

Can you conclude.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is defined for all $x$, the limit of $f$ at $x=a$ exists *if and only if* the two one-sides limits, approaching $a$ from the left and from the right, exist and are equal.

In your case, find the following four one-sided limits:
$$\color{blue}{\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)} \; , \; \color{blue}{\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)} \quad ; \quad \color{red}{\lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x)} \; , \; \color{red}{\lim_{x \to 1^+} f(x)}$$

Now:

- if the blue limits are equal, $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ exists;
- if the red limits are equal, $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$ exists.

Can you take it from there?

---

Hoover over:

> You should find **no** (at $x=0$) and **yes** (at $x=1$).